# Merging elements of different cells

Tags: matlab, cell

Suppose, we have a cell array consisting of ids and one attribute, e.g.

```
A{1,1}=[1 2;2 4]
A{1,2}=[2 3 5;8 5 6]
```

Now, I'd like to have a final output consisting of unique ids of two cells (first row values) and corresponding columns have attribute value of each cell separately. 
i.e.

```
C = 
[1]    [         2]
[2]    [1x2 double]  % 4 in first cell and 8 in second cell
[3]    [         5]
[5]    [         6]
```

it seems that it's not possible to use something like `C=[unique(A{1,:}(1,:)')]`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that each cell has two rows and a variable amount of columns where the first row is the ID and the second row is an attribute, I'd consolidate all of the cells into a single 2D matrix and use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  `accumarray` is very suitable here because you want to group values that belong to the same ID together and apply a function to it.  In our case, our function will simply place the values in a cell array and we'll make sure that the values are sorted because the values that are grouped by `accumarray` per ID come into the function in random order.

Use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert the cells into a 2D matrix, transpose it so that it's compatible for `accumarray`, and use it.  One thing I'll need to note is that should any IDs be missing, `accumarray` will make this slot empty.  What I meant by missing is that in your example, the ID 4 is missing as there is a gap between 3 and 5 and also the ID 6 between 5 and 7 (I added the example in your comment to me). Because the largest ID in your data is 7, `accumarray` works by assigning outputs from ID 1 up to ID 7 in increments of 1.  The last thing we would need to tackle is to eliminate any empty cells from the output of `accumarray` to complete the grouping.

BTW, I'm going to assume that your cell array consists of a **single** row of cells like your example.... so:

```
%// Setup
A{1,1}=[1 2;2 4];
A{1,2}=[2 3 5;8 5 6];
A{1,3}=[7;8];

%// Convert row of cell arrays to a single 2D matrix, then transpose for accumarray
B = cell2mat(A).';

%// Group IDs together and ensure they're sorted
out = accumarray(B(:,1), B(:,2), [], @(x) {sort(x)});

%// Add a column of IDs and concatenate with the previous output
IDs = num2cell((1:numel(out)).');
out = [IDs out];

%// Any cells from the grouping that are empty, eliminate
ind = cellfun(@isempty, out(:,2));
out(ind,:) = [];
```

We get:

```
out = 

    [1]    [         2]
    [2]    [2x1 double]
    [3]    [         5]
    [5]    [         6]
    [7]    [         8]

>> celldisp(out(2,:))

ans{1} =

     2         

ans{2} =

     4
     8
```

---

If you'd like this done on a 2D cell array, where each row of this cell array represents a separate instance of the same problem, one suggestion I have is to perhaps loop over each row.  Something like this, given your example in the comments:

```
%// Setup
A{1,1}=[1 2;2 4];
A{1,2}=[2 3 5;8 5 6];
A{1,3}=[7;8];
A{2,1}=[1 2;2 4]; 
A{2,2}=[1;7];

%// Make a cell array that will contain the output per row
out = cell(size(A,1),1);

for idx = 1 : size(A,1)
     %// Convert row of cell arrays to a single 2D matrix, then transpose for accumarray
      B = cell2mat(A(idx,:)).';

      %// Group IDs together and ensure they're sorted
      out{idx} = accumarray(B(:,1), B(:,2), [], @(x) {sort(x)});

      %// Add a column of IDs and concatenate with the previous output
      IDs = num2cell((1:numel(out{idx})).');
      out{idx} = [IDs out{idx}];

      %// Any cells from the grouping that are empty, eliminate
      ind = cellfun(@isempty, out{idx}(:,2));
      out{idx}(ind,:) = [];
end
```

We get:

```
>> out{1}

ans = 

    [1]    [         2]
    [2]    [2x1 double]
    [3]    [         5]
    [5]    [         6]
    [7]    [         8]

>> out{2}

ans = 

    [1]    [2x1 double]
    [2]    [         4]

>> celldisp(out{1}(2,:))

ans{1} =

     2

ans{2} =

     4
     8

>> celldisp(out{2}(1,:))

ans{1} =

     1

ans{2} =

     2
     7
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Just a point, my cell is single row but with variable number of column e.g. `A{1,3}=[7;8]` and also I'd like to have ids in the first column of the final output too (using something like `unique`). So, I 'm able to know which output is for which id. Will your solution be changed to incorporate these changes?

Comment: @hamideh - Changed. This should also work for as many columns as you want per cell, provided there are **two rows**.  But yes, as long as your cell array consists of a single row of cells, this will work.

Comment: @hamideh - It works for me.  I also added in your example of `A{1,3} = [7;8];`.  You must make sure that you have a single **row** of cells, where each cell has **two rows**.  Check my edits.

Comment: @hamideh - It was my pleasure.  Good luck!

Comment: One more question please, The solution works very fine on the case that I've one row of input. But in fact I've several row of input, each having different number of columns e.g. (`A{2,1}=[1 2;2 4]; A{2,2}=[1;7]`) and I needed to have cell output of two columns for each rows. i.e `out{1}` = your answer and `out{2}` for the result of cell 2 items and so on. So I though in your solution I can change `cell2mat(A).'` to cell2mat(A{i,:}).'` for each row of data; but it gives error of `Error using cell2mat; Too many input arguments.` . Any suggestion please?

Comment: @hamideh - Try doing `cell2mat(A(i,:)).'`.  You are using `{}` instead of `()` which will return a comma-separated list.  That's why you're getting the too many input arguments error.  Looping over each row independently should work, but make sure you're slicing into your cell array properly.

Comment: Exactly! I got the desired answer! You saved me a lot of time and effort. Thanks again:)

Comment: @hamideh - No problem :) I've edited my post to account for the multiple rows.  Good luck!

Comment: @hamideh - BTW, feel free to stop by our MATLAB chat room if you need more help: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - Good luck!

Comment: Great! Now, I'm going to find 'max' value for each entry of 'output' structure found above. When I use `my_out{i} = max(out{i})` and expect to have e.g. 8 for `i=2` i got the following error: `Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'cell'.` It seems cellfun should help me.. Any hint for this new challenge, please?

Comment: @hamideh - `mv_out = cellfun(@(x) max(cell2mat(x(:,2))), out);`

Comment: Thank you rayryerng, Your solution will give the maximum of second column for each entry. but in fact i'm searching to find max for each inner item. i.e. `out{i}(j,:)`; so for row1 (out{1}) I should have 5 max item of `2, 8, 5,6,8` and for row2 (out{2}) I should have `7` and `4` as the output. So, I'm changing my variable sized cell to two column one.. Now, will you guide me how to manipulate your solution?

Comment: Using your hint, I found the solution like this integrated in the first for loop of your solution: `for idxx=1:size(out{idx},1)  out_final{idx}(idxx,1) = IDs(idxx); out_final{idx}(idxx,2) = num2cell(max(cell2mat(out{idx}(idxx,2:end))).');  end`   So we can find max value of each item. Thanks again:)